# MySQL C++ query Access Violation

Tags: c++, mysql

I have a DLL where I make a connection to a MySQL database. I have Open(), Close(), Update(), and Find() functions. The Update() functions inserts data into a table and this works just fine. The Find() function however is just doing a simple query against the same table. When I call the resultset getXX() function I'm getting an Access Violation error and I can't figure out why. What am I missing? Note the query is a view and not a direct table but I wouldn't think that would matter.

```
MT4_EXPFUNC int __stdcall Find(char* pair)
{
try
{
    sql::Statement  *stmt;
    sql::ResultSet* res;
    string p = pair;
    string buysell = "";
    string qry = "select * from forex.GPBUSD_CURRENT_PRICE";

    stmt = _connection->createStatement();

    res = stmt->executeQuery(qry);

    // if we have a record it means we have a trade chance
    if(res->next())
    {
        buysell = res->getString(1);     // ACCESS VIOLATION ERROR HERE
    }

    // clean up
    delete res;
    delete stmt;

    if(buysell == "SELL")
        return 1;
    else if(buysell == "BUY")
        return 2;
    else
        return 0;
}
catch(sql::SQLException &e)
{
    return -1;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

have you considered if getString is a zero indexed method? Or if it's a null datatype your trying to access? or shoot just because res->next() works and doesn't crash, doesn't mean that   res is a valid ptr.

Comment: I have more than 1 column so even if it's zero index it should pull a column. It also shouldn't be null as I'm running the query in MySQL workbench and it's returning the result. If it is NULL how do you check for that before reading?

Comment: I placed a if(!res->isNull(1)) before it and it passed that check so it's not null.

Comment: So if res isn't a valid pointer what could be causing that? That's the issue. Why wouldn't it be valid?

Comment: OK I've narrowed it down to the getString() function. getDouble() and getInt() work. Still not sure why the string wouldn't.

Comment: So this query is a view and the columns I'm trying to get with getString() are columns I've made in the view that don't exist in the table. I say case when condition then 'BUY' else 'SELL' end as direction. So I'm creating the direction column in the view myself. There must be another way you have to get that data.

Comment: have you tried actually stepping into the getString function and seing what's going on? or actually looking at the data type representation of res?  Learn some basic assembly, have some fun.